# Highcharts multiple stock series tooltip show

Tags: highcharts, series

I have a question about several stock charts.
Put the series data into an array by name.
Hovering over the chart shows only one data.
I am curious how to make several together.

My `code` is here:
https://jsfiddle.net/HongRaeCho/rxpjy7nu/

[image: 1.png]
[image: 2.png]

Comment: Hi @해품달, Could you describe your problem more precisely? Also, your jsfiddle doesn't work.

Comment: Thank you. Looking at your answer, I identified and fixed the problem in my code. Now the output is fine.

Comment: Unfortunately, it still doesn't work.